# How to set polygon fill based on imported parameters from postGIS

Tags: ajax, openlayers, polygon, fill

Have successfully imported polygons in OpenLayers along with popup of pertinent data. Need guidance on assigning fill colors from parameters passed via ajax.

## **your text**Hoping to assign fill color based on setting parameter in json file. Currently using:

```
var polyStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: [12,240,60]
}),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: [0,0,0], width: 1
    })
  });
```

***to load the following:***
const  layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
source: new ol.source.Vector({
features:features,
projection: 'EPSG: 3857'
}),
style: polyStyle
});

*I next tried the following as a test based on the "settings feature the file:*

// Polygons style

```
 var setfcolor = function(features) {
   console.log(features);
   var fcolor;
   if (feature.get("setting")=='Carbonate'){
     fcolor = "blue";
   } else if (feature.get("setting")=='Clastic: continental'){
     fcolor = "yellow";
   } else if (feature.get("setting")=='Extrusive: mafic'){
     fcolor = "brown";
   }
};
```

*But it fails and reverts to all blac*k.

*Snippet of json file is:*
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
{
"type": "Feature",
"geometry": {
"type": "Polygon",
"coordinates": [
[
[
-45.499757432,
60.988125868
],
[
-45.49967049,
60.988157751
],
[
-45.497458466,
60.989470026
],
[
-45.487258845,
60.995518876
],
[
-45.483858593,
60.999870372
],
[
-45.483858591,
60.99987019
],
[
-45.465241806,
60.991366687
],
[
-45.450273556,
60.988997409
],
[
-45.422944921,
60.990687369
],
[
-45.42294477,
60.990687194
],
[
-45.419225021,
60.984549241
],
[
-45.412472331,
60.973399399
],
[
-45.502278621,
60.96070259
],
[
-45.525166866,
60.957726342
],
[
-45.544395412,
60.955624111
],
[
-45.572353843,
60.951692596
],
[
-45.655768925,
60.94244974
],
[
-45.670854236,
60.94123391
],
[
-45.693899808,
60.940200373
],
[
-45.664305174,
60.947778021
],
[
-45.659448977,
60.949020163
],
[
-45.648191047,
60.951923402
],
[
-45.636669092,
60.954825483
],
[
-45.565410441,
60.967827923
],
[
-45.523123774,
60.979977384
],
[
-45.517219284,
60.981999
],
[
-45.517218946,
60.981999115
],
[
-45.5059008,
60.985872696
],
[
-45.499757432,
60.988125868
]
]
]
},
"properties": {
"setting_ty": "Supracrustal",
"setting": "Sedimentary and/or volcanic: undivided",
"lithology": "Basalt, sandstone, conglomerate",
"colour_cmy": "20 40 70 0",
"colour": "247"
}
},

[[Polygons and popups working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFej4.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqbV8.jpg)

Comment: See https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-esri.html

Answer (score 0):

Got a good lead from Mike user:10118270 and applied it. I replaced this code:

```
var polyStyle = new ol.style.Style({
  fill: new ol.style.Fill({
    color: [12,202,50]
  }),
  stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
    color: [0,0,0], width: 1
  })
});
```

With the following code:

```
 // Polygons style
 const fillColors = {
   'Slope and deep water': [100,100,100,1],
   'Intrusive: syenitic': [240,10,10,1],
   'Intrusive: gabbroic': [240,10,10,1],
   'Intrusive: anorthositic': [240,10,10,1],
   'Intrusive: tonalitic-granodioritic': [240,10,10,1],
   'Intrusive: granitic':[240,10,10,1],
   'Intrusive: undivided': [230,10,10,1],
   'Sedimentary: undivided': [250,250,10,1],
   'Clastic: shallow marine': [240,240,20,1],
   'Clastic: continental': [255,255,1,1],
   'Clastic: deltaic and nearshore': [240,240,20,1],
   'Marine sedimentary: undivided': [230,230,10,1],
   'Extrusive: mafic': [250,200,10,1],
   'Sedimentary and/or volcanic: undivided': [250,120,10,1],
   'Carbonate': [10,40,255,1],
   'Metamorphic: undivided': [230,10,240,1],
   'ice': [250,250,250,1],
 };

 const style = new ol.style.Style({
   fill: new ol.style.Fill(),
   stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
     color: [0, 0, 0, 1],
     width: 0.5,
   }),
 });
```

The end result is shown below:

[image: geologic polygon]